# 'Last modified' mapped metadata property

Tags: search, metadata

I've created my own mapped metadata property for retrieving 'last modified' data in a sql search.

To the property is mapped the following fields:

**Office:12(Date and Time), creationdate(Date and Time)**

But this property is always null despite items obviously being modified/created.

It's important that I get a consistently populated mapped metadata property for this.

**EDIT: I've tried to use LastModifiedTime but it doesn't seem right? Majority of the dates being returned in this column are today - but nothing's been modified today - not in the way that I know anyway.**

Answer (score 0):

http://sladescross.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/crawled-properties-mappings/#comment-1834

Sorted.............................................